# Multiple Clusters in Quartz Scheduler

Tags: quartz-scheduler

Can we have multiple clusters in Quartz Scheduler?

Assume I have a cluster of server1,server2,server3 and server4 and I'm running 4 jobs (job1,job2,job3, and job4) on this cluster and they are load balanced. [This is working]

Now I want to create groups from the cluster.
Group1 => (server1 and server2)
Group2 => (server3 and server4)

And I want to run 
job1 and job2 on group1 (server1 and server2) and
job3 and job4 on group2 (server3 and server4)

Is it possible to do this and how?

Comment: One way to achieve this is to have separate scheduler for group 1 and 2.

Comment: yeah, that is my last option. In my use case having two separate schedulers is bringing a lot of complexity.

Comment: @rai2048 checking how did you overcome this. I am in a similar situation